# HTTP error 403 forbidden in my test page, nginx server

Tags: php, nginx, config

First time asking a question here. I have a small virtual machine running Windows 10. I've tried to set up a nginx server with PHP and MySQL Workbench. So far nginx default page works and so does MySQL Workbench, but when I try to edit the `nginx.conf` file to change the name of the server, it returns the following error:

> [error] 7896#480: *7 access forbidden by rule, client: 127.0.0.1, server: web.prueba.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "web.prueba.local"

The insides my `nginx.conf` file are the following:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       *:80;
        server_name  web.prueba.local;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            #root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9123;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }         
    }

    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

Edit: This is the working code!

```
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       *:80;
        server_name  www.login.com;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   C:/trabajos;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

        location ~ \.php$ {
            #root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9123;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}

    location /phpmyadmin {
        root   C:/nginx-1.16.1/nginx-1.16.1;
                index    index.php;
        try_files    $uri $uri/ C:/nginx-1.16.1/nginx-1.16.1/phpmyadmin/index.php;

        location ~ ^/assets\.*\.php$ {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                    root           C:/nginx-1.16.1/nginx-1.16.1/phpmyadmin;
                    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9123;
                    fastcgi_index  index.php;
                    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/index.php;
                    include        fastcgi_params;
            }
        }
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

Comment: First guess: you have an `index.php` in wherever `root html` maps to.  Your config specifies PHP requests should be passed to `127.0.0.1:9123`, but there is no sign here of any server configured to listen on port 9123.  Other things to check - if not `index.php`, do you have an `index.html` in that location?  Are permissions correct?  Does that unqualified `html` dir actually exist, maybe try fully qualifying it?  Minor note - about half of your config file is commented out, so why include it here?  Less code to read and parse is always better :-)

Comment: I indeed have a index.php in the folder html, but creating an index.html returns the same error. About port 9123, its the port i open php-cgi with.

Comment: Just creating an `index.html` is not enough, it will never be served because `index.php` has preference in your config: `index  index.php index.html ... `.  Remove `index.php` from there, and restart nginx.  If you see your html file, then you know the problem is in your nginx PHP config.  If you still see the same error, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: It seems the message i posted earlier didn't go through. Neither of the Index worked. I managed to solve It though, ill post the nginx.config after i get home

Comment: Posted the correct code

Comment: Great you managed to solve it.  The idea of SO is to help future visitors who have the same or similar problems.  If you think your solution might help anyone else, post it as an answer (and upvote/accept it), not an edit to your question.  Ideally explain what you did also - eg I scanned through your updated code and the only diff I can see is a `/phpmyadmin` block, which won't solve anything you mentioned in the original question.

Comment: Thats why i've decided against using it as an answer. There is something very small im missing and there is no way its working, as in mine the phpmyadmin block wasn't even present. Its a faulty solution, if you wish